# Cannot find module '.../models/user' nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I've got a problem with require.
I've got a users.js inside folder 'router'. In users.js everything works great with

```
let User = require('../models/user');
```

But when users.js file getting bigger I wanted to part this file into a few files like login.js regiseter.js and so on. I created a folder 'users' inside 'router' and put there those files  (login.js, register.js)

I changed my require to

```
let User = require('.../models/user');
```

Now I got an error:

> Cannot find module '.../models/user'
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb5To.png)

Comment: take the snapshot of your directory structure as you have created a folder inside router. I don't see any code requiring `router` folder that contains `users`

Comment: you have to go 2 steps out. let User = require('../../models/user');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like your require for `login.js` and `register.js` should now be:

`let User = require('../../models/user');`

This will step down two directories before opening the models folder. This assumes from your post the initial structure was:

```
|-- app/
    |-- router/
        |-- users.js
    |-- models/
        |-- user.js
```

and the new structure is:

```
|-- app/
    |-- router/
        |-- users/
            |-- login.js
            |-- register.js
        |-- users.js
    |-- models/
        |-- user.js
```

Comment: That's great! Good luck on your app!