# Node.js Error MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I`m creating login system for my chatapp and I got stuck on error MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
I was following tutorial and I used same code as tutorial
here is the code:

userControllers.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const sha256 = require('js-sha256')
const jwt = require('jwt-then')

exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body

    const emailRegex = /@gmail.com|@yahoo.com|@hotmail.com|@outlook.com|@live.com/

    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) throw 'Your Email domain is not supported.'
    if (password.length < 6) throw 'Your password needs to be at least 6 characters long.'

    const userExists = await User.findOne({
        email,

    })
    if (userExists) throw 'User already exists.'

    const user = new User({ name, email, password: sha256(password + process.env.SALT),
    })


    await user.save()

    res.json({
        message: 'User [' + name + '] registered successfully!'
    })
}

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email,
        password: sha256(password + process.env.SALT),
    })
  if (!user) throw 'Email and Password doesnt`t match!'

  const token = await jwt.sign({id: user.id}, process.env.SECRET)

  res.json({
      message: 'User logged in successfully!',
      token,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything in Mongoose starts with a Schema. Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection.

First, you need to define a schema for your User model.

Create a file `User.js` in your `models` directory,

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const { Schema } = mongoose

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
})

export default mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Now in your `userControllers.js` use `const User = require('./models/User')` to use your model.

Comment: I literally did it in /routes/User.js and in tutorial is no error, and I have the same code, link to tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edrFbieDmv8&lc=UgxgHFc5hjpTNVBpPEp4AaABAg

Comment: Have u added `mongoose.model('user', userSchema)` ? Then import it as `const User = require('./routes/User')` Ideally `Schema` should be defined in your `models` dir.

Comment: Even though I did const User = require('/models/User.js') I get error Error: Cannot find module '/models/User.js'

Comment: Have you moved your schema to `models/User.js` then It should be `/models/User` no need of `.js` extension.

Comment: Jagan, still nothing.

Comment: Actually, User.js is in models folder.

Comment: Still the same error? Have you checked the exports?

Comment: ```module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)``` is the export in User.js model

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './models/User.js' is the error I get

Comment: Can you share the folder structure? Also look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830662/cannot-find-module-models-user-nodejs

Comment: Ohh I fixed it!, Instead of ./models/User.js I needed to put ../models/User.js. Thanks for replies, ```const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../models/User')
mongoose.model('User', 'userSchema')```